# Unable to install APT Google Cloud public signing key and Kubernetes APT repository

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the instructions on the official Kubernetes documentation to install Kubernetes repository, I run

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

but I get 500 error

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 500
```

Visiting the URL or `curl`ing it returns 500 Error

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 500 (Internal Server Error)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>500.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Is Google having issues at the moment or am I missing something?

This is the official documentation URL (Debian distribution tab)
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

**UPDATE**
There is a GitHub issue opened as well https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/116068

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there seem to be an issue. Docs still suggests that URL should be used. Yet I see to 500 too.

Checking google status page ( https://status.cloud.google.com/ ), there could be an issue with FileStore (file access issues for non-root users). With a bunch of affected locations.

---

and right now it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, what would you expect as an answer. To the question, that you posted, which is, and I quote: "Is Google having issues at the moment or am I missing something?"

Comment: And it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could grab that key from the Internet cache - https://web.archive.org/web/20230223152417/https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg - this worked for me just now

Thus your Kubectl installation step would become:

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://web.archive.org/web/20230223152417/https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

Answer (score -3):

Problem has been solved by kubernetes. The solution is to use this URL https://dl.k8s.io/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)